# React-Bootstrap pull right navbar

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` for styling my website. I want to add `Navbar` where all of the elements are mirrored to the right.

```
export default class XNavbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
return (
  <Navbar inverse fluid >

    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="#">Brand</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>

    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Hello</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">World</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>

  </Navbar>
)}
}
```

The result is
[image]

But what I actually want it to be

```
[                                                           World Hello Brand ]
```

I tried using `pullRight` on the `<Navbar` but it didn't work. I also added `<html dir="rtl">`, but this also didn't help. How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried adding `pullRight` to `Navbar.Header`?

Comment: Yes it did nothing.. I have tried adding `pullRight` to every element in the above code.

Comment: interesting. [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs) says that it should be applied on `Nav` elements.

Comment: can you update your code in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t9sf5u9n/

Comment: I don't know how to add the react components, since I'm also using `babel` and `webpack`..

Comment: In my case, I need to set `Nav` style. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55392516/911408).

Answer (score 21):

For those of you, like me, can't get `pullRight` work, it seems that adding the `ml-auto` works better.

```
   <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="ml-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#one">One</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#two">Two</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
```

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54684784/95552

Answer (score 15):

In case you haven't already figured this out, or someone else stumbles on it.    All you should have to do is add the **pullRight** prop to the actual **Nav** component.  The result should be a Brand Logo in the left,  and the navigation pulled to the right.

```
return (
  <Navbar inverse fluid >

    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="#">Brand</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>

    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Hello</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">World</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>

  </Navbar>
)}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but my resulting page looks like [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/LvDfja8). Any idea why that could be the case? I'm pretty sure I don't have any CSS that could be messing with the position...

Comment: Sorry @pfincent , I think I'd need to see your code, or a live link to the page.

Comment: `pullRight` doesn't work for me, but `className="ml-auto"` did. Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54684784/95552

Comment: I think `<Nav.Item>Menu Item</Nav.Item>` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, according to the documentation of Bootstrap React `pullRight` should do it. But I wasn't able to realize it either. I found a working solution which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060358/using-pullright-prop-overflows-right-floated-nav-react-bootstrap-react/54684784#54684784). Just use `<Nav className="ml-auto">`

Comment: `pullRight` doesn't work for me, but `className="ml-auto"` did. Found the solution here: stackoverflow.com/a/54684784/95552

Comment: Well, you point to the same link I did. Not sure why this is necessary ....

Answer (score 0):

You can put your elements inside a div and than float div to right by this css property

```
.exampleDiv {
   float: right;
 }
```

Comment: It also doesn't work well. It shrinks the `exampleDiv` to the right and put each element in a different line.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle