# React bootstrap Navbar: How to right align a navbar item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to right align a navbar item (Contribute) within a `navbar.js` but I can't seem to figure it out.  The navbar is a React component and looks like the following,

**navbar.js** [here](https://github.com/ipatch/crj-frontend/blob/master/src/components/common/navbar.js)

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router'
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

// create classes
var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
              <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <NavBrand linkTo={this.props.brand.linkTo} text={this.props.brand.text} />
          </div>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <NavMenu links={this.props.links} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
});

var NavBrand = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <Link to={ this.props.linkTo }>
        <span className="navbar-brand">{this.props.text}</span>
      </Link>
    );
  }
});

var NavMenu = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var links = this.props.links.map(function(link){
      if(link.dropdown) {
        return (
          <NavLinkDropdown key={link.text} links={link.links} text={link.text} active={link.active} />
        );
      }
      else {
        return (
          <NavLink key={link.text} linkTo={link.linkTo} text={link.text} active={link.active} />
        );
      }
    });
    return (
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
        {links}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

var NavLinkDropdown = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var active = false;
    var links = this.props.links.map(function(link){
      if(link.active){
        active = true;
      }
      return (

        <NavLink key={link.text} linkTo={link.linkTo} text={link.text} active={link.active} />

      );
    });
    return (
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li className={"dropdown" + (active ? "active" : "")}>
        <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          {this.props.text}
          <span className="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
          {links}
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>

    );
  }
});

var NavLink = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <li className={(this.props.active ? "active" : "")}>
        {/*<a href={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text}</a>*/}
        <Link to={ this.props.linkTo }>
          <span className="NavLink">{this.props.text}</span>
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = NavBar;
```

Presently, my navbar looks like the following,

[image: navbar]

Comment: would you expect the order to remain the same, and the brand to stay left aligned? or are you looking for a "right-to-left" style solution?

Comment: I was trying with ml-auto, it didn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65562241/8287187
This helped me out. Long story Short, use ms-auto if ml-auto is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code solved my issue of alignment.

```
var NavMenu = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var links = this.props.links.reduce(function(acc, current){      
      current.dropdown ? acc.rightNav.push(current) : acc.leftNav.push(current);
      return acc;
    }, { leftNav: [], rightNav: [] });
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          {links.leftNav.map( function(link) {
            return <NavLink key={link.text} linkTo={link.linkTo} text={link.text} active={link.active} />
          })}
        </ul>
        {
          links.rightNav.length > 0 ?
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              {
                links.rightNav.map( function(link) {
                  return <NavLinkDropdown key={link.text} links={link.links} text={link.text} active={link.active} />
                })
              }
            </ul> : false
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 40):

The best and easiest approach which works is to add following class to the NAV node like following:

```
<Nav className="ml-auto">
```

Unfortunately adding "pullRight" wasn't the solution and it won't work.

Comment: After so many tries and hacking, this single liner saved me. This works!

Comment: Thank you so much for this single line of code! Hahaha helped out a headache

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 24):

This one works for me

```
<Navbar>
    <Navbar.Brand href="/">MyBrand</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
    <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav className="justify-content-end" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            ...
        </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: My problem with this one is it doesn't seem to work with two <Nav> elements, the second one just goes next to the first one regardless of whatever alignment style class I'm using

Answer (score 22):

The other way you could do it is:

`<Nav className="ms-auto">`

Unfortunately adding "pullRight" wasn't the solution and it won't work.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make your navigation look something like as shown in below screen shot:[image]

Then you would need to apply the class `container-fluid` on `Nav` and class `ml-auto` on the `Nav.Item` on the navigation item which you wish to right align.

Below is the code:

```
<Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
  <Nav className="container-fluid">
    <Nav.Item>
      <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/">Demo App</Navbar.Brand>
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/user-list">User List</Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Link onClick={handleClickUserLogOut}>Log Out</Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item className="ml-auto">
      <Nav.Link>Hi fname lname!</Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: Does not work as of 8/30/21, all items are evenly spread out across the navbar after copy-pasting the exact code.

Answer (score 8):

For those with version 5 of bootstrap, we have to use `ms-auto` instead of `ml-auto` because there has been migration and changes in the class name.

> .ml-* and .mr-* to .ms-* and .me-*

Answer (score 7):

In Bootstrap 5 you can use use `ms-auto` instead of `ml-auto` or `mr-auto`

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me on version - 'v2.0.0-rc.0 (Bootstrap 5.1)'

```
<Nav className='ms-auto'>
```

complete,

```
<Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
    <Nav className='ms-auto'>
        <Nav.Link href='/cart'>Cart</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href='/login'>Sign In</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the class `navbar-right` the reach what you want

Answer (score 1):

So far, I've discovered an easier way to do it from their official documentation, though it may be a little unconventional.

Here's the code

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
  <Container>
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
{/*This totally empty navbar with the class 'me-auto' is significant. */}
    <Nav className="me-auto">
    </Nav>
{/*It is responsible for the other nav bar content moving to the right.*/}
    <Nav>
      <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
        Dank memes
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```

[Sample of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBur6.png)

The simple hack is to add an empty nav bar before your own nav bar content with the class me-auto, as shown below.

```
{/*This is the hack */}
    <Nav className="me-auto">
    </Nav>
{/*Any nav bar created beneath this now aligns to the right.*/}
```

You can ask questions if you don't quite understand.

Comment: This worked for me but not sure if this would be the best possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

Give css property `float : left` to the division or to whatever you want to align right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can target the dropdown menu with a `dropdown-menu-right` to align the Contribute nav item right. [bootstrap dropdown alignment docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment)

Comment: tried adding `right` to `dropdown-menu` thus making `dropdown-menu-right` but it did not pull the navbar item `Contribute` to the right unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like the markup may be a problem. Your dropdown menu is a `ul` within a `li`. The class `dropdown-menu-right` will align right the dropdown menu to that of the parent. Unless that `li` item stretches to the end of the navbar container, the contribute dropdown won't move.

Comment: I think your on to something.

Answer (score 0):

add a

> div className='Navbar'

before  <navbar.Toggle> and add CSS item

```
.Navbar{ justify-content: flex-end;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 5, use **ms-auto** class name to shift the nav links to right. ms-auto stands for margin left(s-start)

```
<Nav className="ms-auto">
```

I used the same solution and it worked for me.